# Error with BDC Model in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, bdc-model

I have an error when I want to update an element in an external SharePoint list :

> "Application error when access /_layouts/15/listform.aspx, Error=Impossible de trouver le formulaire de modification par défaut pour la liste ListePersonneV2". ListePersonneV2 is my external SharePoint list who is connected to a DB Oracle.
>   I have written methods DELETE, READITEM and READLIST and I don't have any problem for these.

Here you have the XML code of the function Update :

```
<Method Name="Update">
              <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="personne" Direction="In">
                  <TypeDescriptor Name="Personne" IsCollection="false" TypeName="BDCtestProject.BdcModel.Personne, BdcModel">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="CODE" IdentifierName="CODE" IsCollection="false" TypeName="System.Int32" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="NOM" IdentifierName="NOM" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="PRENOM" IdentifierName="PRENOM" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="ADRESSE" IdentifierName="ADRESSE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="NUM_TELEPHONE" IdentifierName="NUM_TELEPHONE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" /></TypeDescriptors></TypeDescriptor></Parameter>
              </Parameters>
              <MethodInstances>
                <MethodInstance Name="Update" Type="Updater" />
              </MethodInstances></Method>
```

The error appears when I try to alter an element on a SharePoint external list, and the error is described in the log file.

Comment: Have you forgot to add the XML code in the question? You could edit it if you need. Also, it would help if you leave a basic translation of the error message for people that doesn't speak French.

Comment: You forgot to mark your XML as code in editor (select it and press "{ }" button). That's why it is invisible. I made this change. Please, approve it to allow others to see XML.

Answer (score 1):

XML Code of Update method :

```
<Method Name="Update">
              <Parameters>
                <Parameter Name="personne" Direction="In">
                  <TypeDescriptor Name="Personne" IsCollection="false" TypeName="BDCtestProject.BdcModel.Personne, BdcModel">
                    <TypeDescriptors>
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="CODE" IdentifierName="CODE" IsCollection="false" TypeName="System.Int32" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="NOM" IdentifierName="NOM" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="PRENOM" IdentifierName="PRENOM" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="ADRESSE" IdentifierName="ADRESSE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" />
                      <TypeDescriptor Name="NUM_TELEPHONE" IdentifierName="NUM_TELEPHONE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" /></TypeDescriptors></TypeDescriptor></Parameter>
              </Parameters>
              <MethodInstances>
                <MethodInstance Name="Update" Type="Updater" />
              </MethodInstances></Method>
```

Error=Impossible de trouver le formulaire de modification par défaut pour la liste ListePersonneV2" means **"impossible to find the default updater method form for the list ListePersonneV2"**

Comment: Error in english : "Failed to find the default form for updating external SharePoint list"

Comment: I had the same problem with the function 'Create' and I have resolved it. I have added a form whith SharePoint Designer, it's name is 'NewForm.aspx' whith the option new element and now I can add an element on my list. But the problem is that SharePoint Designer doesn't accept that I add an other form for editing elements.

Comment: Hello, Today I have deleted my model that was deployed on SharePoint. I have regenerated the solution of my project and deployed the solution and now, SharePoint Designer has created the EditForm.aspx. So I can alter an element from a list, however, when I want to alter an element in my external list SharePoint redirects me on an empty form.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that at least order of the closing tags in XML is incorrect. 
If it doesn't help, please let us know.

Your part of XML:

```
<TypeDescriptor Name="NUM_TELEPHONE" IdentifierName="NUM_TELEPHONE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" /></TypeDescriptors></TypeDescriptor></Parameter>
```

You don't need to close "TypeDescriptor" tag as it is self-closed ("/>"). So it should be:

```
<TypeDescriptor Name="NUM_TELEPHONE" IdentifierName="NUM_TELEPHONE" TypeName="System.String" UpdaterField="true" /></TypeDescriptors></Parameter>
```

Comment: It doesn't help, because I need to close "TypeDescryptor" tag, I open it in this line : <TypeDescriptor Name="Personne" IsCollection="false" TypeName="BDCtestProject.BdcModel.Personne, BdcModel">

Comment: Ooops, sorry, you are right. I missed it. Unfortunately, I haven't worked with updater for a long time, but as I remember you don't need IdentifierName attribute on all the descriptors and it should be only on the ID (Code? in your case). Let me know if the problem is not in Identifiers

Comment: ClientBDCModel.bdcm : Entity name : Client           Identifiers : CODE (int) , NOM (String) , ADRESSE (String)       Methods : ReadItem, Create, ReadList, Delete, Update            Function Update : return : void                                  -                 parameter : client,                        -      type Descriptor Client -> has 3 types descryptors      --> when I delete one type descriptor, there is a compilation error

Comment: I mean as I understand you don't need to mark all TypeDescriptors as Identifiers (not all of them are ID). For instance, here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee559296(v=office.14).aspx IdentifierName attribute is defined only for CustomerId.